# Unable to configure Azure Insights on Azure VM running Windows

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring, azure-analytics

I am attempting to configure the Log Analytics agent for Insights on my Azure VM running Windows. When I attempt to deploy the monitoring configuration, the DependencyAgentWindows VM extension fails to install. I have the same solution working on a similar VM and am stumped on what the issue is for the failing VM.
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6F0c.png)]

> {"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment> operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details.> Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage
> details.","details":"code":"VMExtensionHandlerNonTransientError","message":"The
> handler for VM extension type
> 'Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent.DependencyAgentWindows'
> has reported terminal failure for VM extension
> 'DependencyAgentWindows' with error message: 'Install failed for
> plugin (name:
> Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent.DependencyAgentWindows,
> version 9.10.16.22650) with exception Command
> C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent.DependencyAgentWindows\9.10.16.22650\scripts\RunPs1.cmd
> of Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent.DependencyAgentWindows
> has exited with Exit code: 52'.\r\n    \r\n'Install handler failed for
> the extension. More information on troubleshooting is available at
> [https://aka.ms/VMExtensionDependencyAgentWindowsTroubleshoot'"}]}](https://aka.ms/VMExtensionDependencyAgentWindowsTroubleshoot%27%22%7D%5D%7D)

I have tried to deploying the Monitoring Configuration and installing the DepencyAgentWindows VM Extension through the Portal and through PowerShell. I am expecting the DepencyAgentWindows VM Extension to install properly and be able to enable Insights successfully.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce same in my environment I got the results successfully like below.***

This issue usually occurs if network connectivity issues preventing the plugin from being downloaded and if the extension won't work properly if the vm agent is failing to report a status to the Azure platform..

To resolve this issue:

Try to delete if any other extension is already exists in your vm

In virtual machine -> extension -> uninstall

[image]

In monitor -> virtual machine -> configure insights -> enable -> monitoring configuration -> configure

[image]

When I try to deploy, it deployed successfully like below:

[image]

If still issue persists, try to uninstall the vm and Redeploy it and also check the [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agents-overview#supported-operating-systems) to know the supported operating system versions.